# toolchains plugin issue in MyEclipse

Tags: java, maven-2, java-6, myeclipse

We are facing following issues in my *MyEclipse*:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-toolchains-plugin:1.1:toolchain (execution: default, phase: validate)

We are using `Maven 2.2.1` and `Java 1.6.0_45` as part of our build. We are not in a position to shift to `Maven 3` or `Java 1.7`.

Also tried to add the `<action> <ignore /> </action>` to our plugin configuration in `pom.xml`, but still the issue persists.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Madhu

Comment: Did you add the <action> to the <pluginManagement> section, as mentioned in [this M2Eclipse help](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html)?

Comment: Why not able to go to Maven 3? Maven 3 is compatible with Maven 2.2.X except for reporting in Maven...So ?Furthermore If you are working with Eclipse you are using already Maven 3+ depending on which version of Eclipse you are using?

Comment: We are working on an existing application and any changes to the infrastructure/build/java etc requires it to go through a rigorous regression testing. At this point , its bit difficult. But we have plans to migrate moving forward. Thanks.